# Assembly not found after deleting package and Rebuild?

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, asp.net-boilerplate

New to asp.net i am trying to run the project described in [asp.net zero docs](https://docs.aspnetzero.com/documents/zero/latest/Developing-Step-By-Step-Xamarin) using **visual studio 2017**.

When i build the project , i get warnings telling the absence of certain assemblies in the project:

```
System.RunTime
System.ObjectModel
System.Collections
System.Runtime
```

Searching for a solution  i deleted the package folder and then rebuilt the project but the same issue repeared.
 i find that i can download the assemblies using *package manager*  with help of [nuget Gallery website](https://www.nuget.org/packages) , however when i install a missing package i get a message telling that the package already exist !!?

```
The package 'System.Collections.4.3.0' already exists in the project 'src \ Acme.PhoneBookDemo.Mobile.Droid'
```

what do you suggest to fix that problem ? or that is just a warning and it isn't important ?

Comment: What is your project type?

Comment: it's name is **Acme.PhoneBook.Mobile.Droid**  ,it dosen't have .csproj  so i can see the output type, but it have the icon of Android

Comment: Fail to open your project at present, it seems you are not developing with asp.net core, you may consult asp.net zero developer for help.